# Netsuite: PHP Toolkit retrieve Item Fulfillment record attached to a Sales Order

Tags: php, netsuite

as the subject says, I would like to be able to retrieve the Item Fulfillment records attached to a Sales Order record, if any, using the PHP Toolkit.

The code below will retrieve the Sales Order and Cash Sale records based on the value of a custom field, but I cannot get it to include an Item Fulfillment record.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$ts = new TransactionSearch();
$tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic();
$csf = new SearchStringCustomField();
$csf->internalId = '69';
$csf->searchValue = '100000137';
$csf->operator = 'is';
$scfl = new SearchCustomFieldList();
$scfl->customField = array($csf);
$tsb->customFieldList = $scfl;
$ts->basic = $tsb;
$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $ts;
$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
```

Comment: Does the same search in the UI yield the results you want? That is debugging step #1 as SuiteTalk very closely resembles the operations in the UI.

Comment: Yes, if I enter the value of that custom field in the NS search UI, it will show me the Cash Sale, the Sales Order and the Item Fulfillment.  http://i.imgur.com/tnTlFtt.jpg

Comment: Global search and your SuiteScript search are different beasts. If you create a Transaction Saved Search in the UI and add a Criteria for the custom field, do you get the Item Fulfillment in the results? I would also make sure the custom field is displayed on the Item Fulfillment Form that your Role is defaulting too. Without knowing what Role SuiteTalk is using it's also worth making sure the Role has access to the Item Fulfillment record, if not you would have results like you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later.. but this is what I could do:

```
function get_item_fulfillment_by_sales_order_internal_id($internal_id) {
    // Crea un objeto RecordRef para representar la Sales Order
    $salesOrderRef = new RecordRef();
    $salesOrderRef->internalId = $internal_id;
    $salesOrderRef->type = 'salesOrder';

    // Crea el campo de búsqueda para el campo 'createdFrom'
    $createdFromField = new SearchMultiSelectField();
    $createdFromField->operator = 'anyOf';
    $createdFromField->searchValue = [$salesOrderRef];

    // Crea la búsqueda básica con el campo 'createdFrom'
    $searchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    $searchBasic->createdFrom = $createdFromField;

    // Crea el objeto de búsqueda
    $search = new TransactionSearch();
    $search->basic = $searchBasic;

    // Crea la solicitud de búsqueda
    $searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    $searchRequest->searchRecord = $search;

    // Realiza la búsqueda
    $searchResponse = NetSuiteSandboxService::getService()->search($searchRequest);
    return $searchResponse->searchResult;
}
```